# pre_limit_mult in synth_runner package stata does not work

Tags: stata

I would like to leave out the placebos with a pre-treatment RMSPE that is 2 times higher than the  one of my treatment unit.
However, when I use the synth_runner command with pre_limit_mult(2) and follow exactly the example they give in the paper, every placebo is still included in the graph. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with an MCVE.

As is explained in the help file, `pre_limit_mult(K)` will exclude placebo states *from inference* if the match quality of that state (measured by pre-treatment Root Mean Squared Predictive Error), is greater than K times the match quality of the treated unit. This does not alter which placebo lines are plotted, it only tends to bring down the p-values.

However, you can just drop the ones you don't want to show in the plot like this:

```
use "smoking.dta", clear
tsset state year

local K = 2 // pre_limit_mult factor

/* all 38 placebos */
synth_runner cigsale beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), trunit(3) trperiod(1989) gen_vars
di e(n_pl)              // The number of placebo averages used for comparison
di e(avg_pre_rmspe_p)   // The proportion of placebos that have a pre-treatment RMSPE at least as large as the average of the treated units
single_treatment_graphs
graph export "raw_all.pdf", name(raw) replace
drop pre_rmspe post_rmspe lead effect cigsale_synth

/* same as above, but p-values change when we exclude 17 states */
synth_runner cigsale beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), trunit(3) trperiod(1989) gen_vars pre_limit_mult(`K')
di e(n_pl)              // The number of placebo averages used for comparison
di e(avg_pre_rmspe_p)   // The proportion of placebos that have a pre-treatment RMSPE at least as large as the average of the treated units
single_treatment_graphs
graph export "raw_all2.pdf", name(raw) replace

/* exclude 17 states from graph */
preserve
    sum pre_rmspe if state=="California":state, meanonly
    gen in_sample = cond(pre_rmspe < = r(mean)*`K',1,0)
    distinct state if in_sample == 1 // CA is counted as in sample, so this matches 21 above
    drop if in_sample == 0
    single_treatment_graphs
    graph export "raw_limited.pdf", name(raw) replace
restore
```

An alternative would be to write a wrapper for the graph commands that does this for you and accepts an `if` option. Might be worth your effort if you plan to do this a lot.

You may need to `ssc install distinct` since that is a user-written command.

Comment: Where did you find `smoking.dta`? Unless i am missing something, the ancillary file with the same name from the `synth` package does not contain these variables.

Comment: @PearlySpencer It comes with `synth` if you `ssc install synth, all`.

Comment: This is really weird. When i download the file it contains the variables `study`, `trt`, `d` and `n`.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Weird, but seems to be true now. Try [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/Synth/smoking.dta).