# pre_limit_mult in synth_runner package does not work well

Tags: stata

This might be similar to this question ([pre_limit_mult in synth_runner package stata does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076841/pre-limit-mult-in-synth-runner-package-stata-does-not-work)), However, I ask this because I could not find any useful tips from the link.

I am trying to use the `pre_limit_mult(real)` option to limit the placebo effects in the pool for inference. The ultimate purpose is to test the validity of estimation of the economic impact of the coup in Gambia in 1994.

However, even though I follow the practice as the guidebook explains, the command does not work and present the message like the following.

```
tsset country_id year
synth rgdpe pop rconna csh_i csh_x rgdpe(1971) rgdpe(1982) rgdpe(1993), trunit(21) trperiod(1994) keep("Gambia_outout") replace fig
local K = 2
synth_runner rgdpe pop rconna csh_i csh_x rgdpe(1971) rgdpe(1982) rgdpe(1993), trunit(21) trperiod(1994) keep("Gambia_outout") replace gen_vars  pre_limit_mult(`K')
single_treatment_graphs, trlinediff(-1) raw_gname( rgdpe_raw) effects_gname(rgdpe_effects) effects_ylabels(-1500(750)1500) effects_ymax(2000) effects_ymin(-2000) do_color(bluishgray)
```

```
With -, gen_vars- the program needs to be able create the following variables: lead rgdpe_sy nth effect pre_rmspe post_rmspe. Please make sure there are no such varaibles and that the dependent variable [rgdpe] has a short enough name that the generated vars are not too long (usually a max of 32 characters)
```

I received this message.

```
With -, gen_vars- the program needs to be able create the following variables: lead rgdpe_synth effect pre_rmspe post_rmspe.
 Please make sure there are no such varaibles and that the dependent variable [rgdpe] has a short enough name that the generated vars are not too long (usually a max of 32 characters).
```

Please download the input data and dofile from the following link (I could not find the way to directly attach the file in stackoverflow).

(https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VyP2GN3NfQT6jQ9enbCvE2VTVNxZdPgc?usp=sharing)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Someone may be willing to do this. On the other hand, reading the help and studying the code for a detailed command is a big ask. I have seen more interest in `synth` on Statalist, so you may be better advised to post there, but if so **please inform both sites about cross-posting**.

Comment: You are already posting on Statalist e.g. https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1684364-how-to-add-conditionality-when-running-placebo-test-in-synthetic-control-method (but not I think this question).